# Read from file negative numbers C++

Tags: c++, numbers

I have to get numbers from file and some of them are negative. So, how can I do that? (C++)

Now I'm trying just this (without something special):

**U1.txt file:**

```
4 5 -1 6 -2
```

**My code:**

```
ifstream fd(FD);
int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
fd>>n1>>n2>>n3>>n4>>n5;
```

Comment: `fd>>n1>>n2>>n3>>n5;` Forgot n4 there.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is basically correct, except for that typo with n4 missing.
This:

```
ifstream fd("U1.txt");
int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
fd>>n1>>n2>>n3>>n4>>n5;
```

Will do what you expect, modulo error conditions.